Wallet, Voucher or Credit payment methods for events
A couple of years ago Pradeep Nayak asked a question about User wallet support in CiviCRM. Did anything come of this? Anyone seen any alternative approaches?
Jan

Stripe Checkout kind of supports this indirectly, since the visitor can use whatever payment methods are available to them, including 3rd party wallet-like things such as googlepay.
